# Python string conversion - date in Zulu format to standard time

Tags: python

How can I convert a string in below format:

```
20221001T0545Z
```

to

```
2022-10-01 05:45
```

The result can just be text or string, it does not need to be an actual date-time

Comment: Well, you can do simple string manipulation for that.  For example, `f"{s[0:4]}-{s[4:6]}-{s[6:8]} {s[9:11]}:{s[11:13]}"`.  I'm not saying that's the best way, but it's easy.  That doesn't change the time zone, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `datetime` library for this conversion, see documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.strptime("20221001T0545Z", "%Y%m%dT%H%MZ")

print(d) # >> '2022-10-01 05:45:00'
print(d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) # >> '2022-10-01 05:45'
```